# Does a module AnimalList have a Uses dependency to Animal?

Tags: architecture

In `Documenting Software Architectures: Views and Beyond` one can read

> *Uses* is a form of dependency that can exist between two modules. A
>   *uses* B if the correctness of A depends on the presence of a correct
>   implementation of B.

Now, does this mean that if I have a `AnimalList` class that is a container for `Animal` instances, but doesn't actually invoke any method on any animal, is there an **Uses** form of dependency from A to B?

It looks to me it doesn't. I can make whatever changes I want to Animal that AnimalList will still be totally oblivious to that fact. It just needs its existence -- nothing more.

Is there any name for this kind of "relationship"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people call it name coupling, because AnimalList depends on an class named Animal. However, this is generally a poor design, except where deficits in the language require it. The correct implementation is to use a parametrized type of some kind. So you implement List, which is entirely decoupled from the contained object.